# SQL Developer 18.3: set alternative schema for individual connections automatically

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using several connections in SQL developer to connect to different Oracle databases. For some connections I have to change the schema to that of another user. This can be done is several ways

1. By using: `alter session set current_schema = <otheruser>;` 
   The drawback is that I have to enter this for every connection I want to open and with a different `<otheruser>` for each connection.
2. Using the global connection startup script in Preferences > Database > Filename for connection startup script. The drawback of this method is that SQL Developer uses the same global startup script and runs it for every connection I open. Probably trying to set a non existing schema in most -but one- connections.

Is there a way to automatically set the default schema on connecting to a database for individual connections?

Connection Schema

- conn_1   Leave current schema unchanged for this connection
- conn_2   Change current schema to `<schema_A>` for this connection
- conn_3   Leave current schema unchanged for this connection
- conn_4   Change current schema to `<schema_B>` for this connection
- conn_5   Change current schema to `<schema_C>` for this connection

A solution will be very helpful.

Comment: Are the connections all to the same DB, and/or as the same user? If so you could possibly figure out which connection you're in within the global script and change to the appropriate schema based on that. Proxy authentication would be simpler, but depends if you have those privs, and actually want to be in that schema as the owner - so you can create/drop things - or just so queries see that schema's objects without prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not a feature. We assume when you define the connection, you are using the schema that you want to work with.

The tool is VERY connection driven - using alter session set current schema will work with queries you run in a SQL Worksheet, but won't have any effect for the rest of the tool, say browsing your tables in the Connection navigation tree.

Now, if you have PROXY connect privs, you could set up your connection to actually connect to your 'default' schema via proxy.

I show how [here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2018/01/using-proxy-connections-in-oracle-sql-developer/)